# Evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, polylogarithm

According to Wolfram Alpha
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{\ln^22}{2}$$
I searched on Wikipedia and learnt that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n}{n^2} = \mathrm{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
In general, the series is related to polylogarithm function
$$\mathrm{Li}_k(z)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^k}$$
However, I do not understand how exactly to use the polylogarithm function to evaluate
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n}{n^2}$$
Could people provide me some assistance?

Comment: I am quite sure that your sum equals $\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac12\right)$ and not $\operatorname{Li}_2(2)$ as you claimed.

Comment: Right, I will make the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third identity here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function#Identities is easily proved by integration
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathrm{Li}_2(z)+\mathrm{Li}_2(1-z) = \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \ln(z) \ln(1-z).
\end{eqnarray*}
Now set $z=1/2$ and we have the result
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathrm{Li}_2 \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 2^n}= \frac{\pi^2}{12} - \frac{1}{2} (\ln(2))^2 .
\end{eqnarray*}